# Delphi IDE begin-end pair indicator

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

In Delphi IDE brackets () are easy to match together because the IDE highlights the matching pair when clicked.

Is there any way to do this with begin-end pairs?
It would definitely improve work efficiency.

Comment: What version of Delphi? Editor and IDE features differ between them, so with questions like this it's relevant to include a version-specific tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in XE2, I didn't find that option.
I use the CnPack (open-source) plug-in; it offers structural highlighting.
Delphi 10 Seattle has it natively (per [feature matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf)).

Comment: Cool I will give it a try